# How to add an attribute (not attribute value) conditionally in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I see a lot of questions where someone asks how to add an attribute in Angular but all the answers use the `ng-attr` solution which as far as i know only sets the **value** of the attribute. I don't want my attribute to appear at all if the conditions are not met.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

[JQuery's `attr()` method](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2) allows you to **set both an attribute name and a value**.

There is an [example of setting an attribute on click](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_attr.asp) at w3Schools, which could easily be adapted for use in other events/conditions inside a custom directive.

**Update...**

[Here is a somewhat trivial example](https://plnkr.co/edit/Hw62lCS3Qf7nnfQ84fYG?p=preview) of conditionally adding the `disabled` attribute to an `input` (textbox) if the word it contains is greater than 8 characters in length.

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.words = ["Floral", "Curious", "Blunder", "Molecular", "Complicated", 
                  "Drops", "Bumper", "Promise", "Clean", "Doubtless" ];
});

app.directive('disableLongWords', function($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    link: function(scope, iElem, iAttrs) {
      console.log(scope.word);
      if (scope.word.length > 8) {
        iElem.children().attr("disabled", "disabled");
      }
    }
  }
});
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <disable-long-words ng-repeat="word in words">
    <input type=text ng-model="word">
    <br>
  </disable-long-words>
</body>
```

Depending on what attribute you are wanting to set and on the occurence of what condition this may be of no use at all, but that's the kind of thing I was thinking of when I made the original suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the the element using 
   `angular.element(element);`

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

After this you can use the 
`.attr()` method.